# Click "Accept" button in Gridview then move the record in another Gridview in different page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, expression, move, transfer

I want a gridview that having **"ACCEPT"** button then after clicking it. I want the accepted record to be moved or transferred in another gridview which is located in another page?

I already have two gridviews:

**Gridview1** named **PendingRecordsGridview**.
**Gridview2** named **AcceptedRecordsGridview**.

I already made a register.aspx page that after clickng register button, It will send the data in PendingRecordsGridview. And It works! And now, Like i said. I want to add "ACCEPT" button in that gridview, so after clicking the accept button. The record will be transfer to AcceptedRecordsGridview (another page) please! Help!

Comment: Do you mean that accepted record should appear in grid at already opened page?

Comment: to make it clear...the PendingRecordsGridview is located at (pending.aspx) page..then the AcceptedRecordsGridvew is located at (accepted.aspx) page. two pages to be exact :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this.. i have tested it..

things you have to keep in mind..

1. you have to create two different tables for your two gridview.. but those table design should be same of tbl1 and tbl2.. in tbl1 make one field as primarykey and make it auto-incremented
2. don't keep any primarykey or and auto-incremented field in tbl2

here on accept button first data will be inserted in to tbl2 and then delete from original table tbl1
page.aspx file

```
            <asp:GridView ID="PendingRecordsGridview" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id"
        onrowcommand="PendingRecordsGridview_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Accept">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button CommandArgument='<%# Bind("id") %>' ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                        CommandName="accept" Text="Accept" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sd1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

now page.aspx.cs file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        bind();
    }
}
protected void bind()
{
    PendingRecordsGridview.DataSource = sd1;
    PendingRecordsGridview.DataBind();
}
protected void PendingRecordsGridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "accept")
    {
        Session["id"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl2 (id, name) SELECT id, name FROM tbl1 where id='"+Session["id"].ToString()+"'", con);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("delete from tbl1 where id='"+Session["id"].ToString()+"'", con);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            bind();

    }
}
```

now just take another page.. and bind it with tbl2 which will be having records which are approved...

feel free to ask regarding this.. and mark it as answer if u found it helpful

Comment: Ow i forgot :)) I'm using AccessDataSource not SQL :)) but i get the point :)

Comment: could you please convert your database in Access? please hehehe :)) and write the code again? please. Your'e going to save my day! super

Comment: i have never used access sorry to say..bt yes you can do tht with access also easily..just use the command argument and command field, you can raise any event by this id, you can update the data with same.. bind your primary key field with it..i have used command field as id u can use your own:))

Comment: Thanks again! :)) your'e marvelous!

Comment: tnxxx peterson.. enjy cody day.. :)

Comment: Error said: BC30456: 'PendingRecordsGridview_RowCommand' is not a member of 'ASP.logon_page_aspx'.

Comment: Your gridview may not have the event wired up in its markup. Try adding in onrowcommand="PendingRecordsGridview_RowCommand" on code of your grideview

Comment: I have that code: <asp:GridView ID="PendingRecordsGridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" onrowcommand="PendingRecordsGridview_RowCommand"> :((

Comment: I believe the cause of this problem my accure due to copying an existing page and renaming it to something else but not checking the class in the .aspx.cs file matched the inherits on the .aspx file. do one thing take a fresh page ans try putting one one thing step by step.. else this will take too much time to find a little error

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED :)) thanks again. sorry I'm not gonna interrupt you again :))